# Cassandra shows incorrect load

Tags: cassandra

[image: docker exec -it cass-node-1 nodetool status casscluster01]

As you can in the output that second node Owns shows 66.1% and Load size is 834.12GB whereas the third node has the lower load size(801.56GB) compared to node2 but Owns percentage is high.

Does this mean, the output is not accurate.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that some of the load is data that the node is not responsible for anymore. For example if you had one node first and loaded it with 100gb. Then you change RF to 2 and add a second node. The first node still has the data even after streaming but it does not own that data. You can remove this data with nodetool cleanup.

Or it could be that a node was down for some time and you haven't run repair yet.

Edit: As Alex mentioned, it's also possible that you have large partitions and then the data won't get distributed as well.

Comment: @AlexOtt True, I forgot about that one.

Answer (score 1):

The percentages *will not* match with your actual data stored on disk.  Note that the heading reads `Owns (effective)`.  That column indicates the percentage of the available token ranges that the node is responsible for.  As each node is responsible for about two-thirds, I'm going to guess that you have specified a replication factor of two.

While Cassandra's Murmur3 hash does a good job of spreading data around evenly, large partitions can put more load on a small number of nodes (as Alex indicated).