# Cassandra disk usage vs nodetool status

Tags: database, cassandra

My Nodetool Status shows something like this

```
UN  x.x.x.x  682.74 GiB  256          ?       d3657220-ee5d-4348-a68e-44cb5020fdf3  1a

UN  y.y.y.y  836.52 GiB  256          ?       748e1de1-d04b-4e51-8828-5e0a7468b64f  1a

UN  z.z.z.z   569.26 GiB  256          ?       4ce10c39-a3e8-437e-8a74-41216ac264ae  1a

UN  k.k.k.k    976.97 GiB  256          ?       479d02c2-2fb7-4cc8-91fe-efa71ba07a
```

But when I run `du -sh /var/lib/cassandra/` or `df -h` they list something like this (copied relevant from each node):

```
/dev/xvda1     1008G  525G  442G  55% /

/dev/xvda1     1008G  458G  510G  48% /

/dev/xvda1     1008G  481G  487G  50% /

/dev/xvda1     1008G  458G  510G  48% /
```

How come I have more data on nodetool status but not actually on the disks, also the disk space seems to be balanced, but nodetool status isn't?

(One more observation, if I restart cassandra on any of the node, disk usage reported by nodetool status is reduced considerably, but no data loss occurs)

Comment: Cassandra version is 3.10

Comment: I have answered a similar question before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791425/cassandra-shows-incorrect-load/47791555